# Compile C++ Code Using The Terminal Directly Without Save File.cpp

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need to compile C++ code directly in the terminal or CLI without saving the file

When is use the below way, It shows me an error.

```
gcc -x c - <<eof
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    cout << "Hello world";
  }
  eof
```

Comment: You are trying to compile a C++ program using a C compiler.  Edit: Why remove the question when you've gotten a working answer?

Comment: If you're trying to compile C++ code, why are you passing `-x c` to tell it to compile as C code?

Comment: "It shows me an error" doesn't help us much. Perhaps you could show us the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile a C++ program using a C compiler.

This works:

```
g++ '-xc++' - <<eof
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world";
}
eof
```

Comment: It doesn't work only executes the code without errors but there is no result

Comment: @MontaserMossallem Yes, you get a program, `a.out`. If you want to run it, then add `./a.out` after `eof`

Comment: @MontaserMossallem C++ is not a script language. G++ does not run the code, it compiles it.

Comment: @MontaserMossallem You've only asked it to compile/link your program. `g++` does not automatically execute the result. To run it, execute the command `./a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a C++ program from a source,
this works:

```
g++ -xc++ - && ./a out <<eof
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world";
}
eof
```